# Multivariable Calculus Integral Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This problem is being very difficult for me to solve, I need help.

Consider $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^1$, suppose that the level curves of $F$ are closed and that $\nabla F$ is never $0$ for $x\neq0$.
Consider the region $D$ between the curves $F=a$ and $F=b$. For each $r$ in $[a,b]$, let $c_r$ be the curve $F=r$. Let $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous.

I have to show that $$\int_Df=\int_a^b\bigg(\int_{c_r}\frac{f}{|\nabla F|}\bigg)dr$$

Usually when I ask something here I show my attempts or my observations, but in this case I couldn't even start doing this!

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: How can the level curves be closed, and yet $\nabla F$ is never $0$ with a $C^1$ function? If $\mathcal{C}$ is some closed level curve, then somewhere in its interior there is either a point of discontinuity, a point with undefined $\nabla$, or a point with $\nabla=0$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Pretend that the graph of $F$ is a paraboloid; it doesn't matter if $\nabla F = 0$ at the origin as long as $0 < a < b$. I agree though that the question should be phrased so that $\nabla F \neq 0$ on the region $D$, however.

Comment: @ABlumenthal But OP says that the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and implies the given conditions apply for all of $F$'s domain. All this is stated before $D,a,b$ are mentioned. I guess it's clear now that you point it out that the $\nabla$ restriction should only apply to $D$.

Comment: This problem comes from a book about vector analysis. I really dont know if there is some mistake there cause I just started to learn, but I think it's ok.
The author is my teacher in he uses his book for years. If there was some mistake someone would tell him and he would tell us.

Comment: That is what I think.

Comment: Use an argument similar to the argument of cylindrical shells, only the base of each cylinder is a level curve, not a circle. That should be a good start.

Comment: There's surely a mistake, but it's not a big one. One way to correct it is to change the condition "$\nabla F$ is never $0$" to "$\nabla F$ is never $0$ for $\vec{x}\neq\vec{0}$".

Comment: Ok. I can discuss about this with my teacher later. Going to edit.

Comment: even with this edit and the idea about cylindrical shells, it's too much complicated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula that needs to be proven is basically the change of variables $(x,y)\rightarrow(F,\tau)$, where $F$ is the level of $f$ and $\tau$ is the natural parameter (curve length) on the level set. It is actually easier to go in the inverse direction: start from the expression on the right where we integrate the function $\frac{f}{|\nabla F|}$. Then, passing from $(F,\tau)$ to $(x,y)$, the integral will transform into
$$ \int_D \frac{f}{|\nabla F|} \left|\frac{D(F,\tau)}{D(x,y)}\right|dxdy,$$
where 
$$ \left|\frac{D(F,\tau)}{D(x,y)}\right|=|\mathrm{det}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial y}
\end{array}\right)|$$
is the jacobian of the variable change.
Hence, all we have to show is that
$$ |\nabla F|=\biggl|\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}\right)\biggr|.\tag{1}$$
But, since the unit vector $\vec{n}$ orthogonal to $\nabla{F}$ (and hence tangent to the level curve) has the form 
$$ \vec{n}=\left(-\frac{1}{|\nabla F|}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},
\frac{1}{|\nabla F|}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right),$$
then $d\vec{l}=\vec{n}d\tau=(dx,dy)\Rightarrow d\tau=n_xdx+n_ydy$, so that
$$ \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x}=n_x=-\frac{1}{|\nabla F|}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\qquad
\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial y}=n_y=\frac{1}{|\nabla F|}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}.$$
Substituting these expressions into (1), we see that it is indeed satisfied.

Comment: I dont understand how do you say $F$ is a variable...because $F$ is a function. I never saw this kind of treatment.

Comment: Imagine that your level sets are circles centered at the origin. Then $F$ and $\tau$ are a kind of radial and angular coordinate, respectively. $F$ is certainly a function of $x,y$ (just as $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is), which is determined in a tricky way by $f$.

Comment: Its beyond my mind...but thanks.

Comment: im just starting to learn this, Im incapable of thinking in $F$ as a "kind of radial something" and just put as a variable. I need something more basic and clear.

Comment: I can only re-suggest to work out an explicit example of what was called "cylindrical shells" above. Put simply, suppose that your function $f(x,y)$ depends only on the combination $x^2+y^2$. Then describe the level sets and try to relate the left and the right side of your relation in this special case. Then try to understand how the things will be modified if the level sets are more complicated - say, if your function depends on the combination $y+x^2$. Good luck.